# VBA SQL pulled data coming back as empty

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I'm pulling into Excel VBA from a SQL ADODB Connection and it seems that some fields are coming back as empty that have values in SQL.  I'm very green in VBA (just diving back into a legacy application to try and migrate everything to SQL Database storage instead of CSVs)

Here's an example of the value return (just a " where we should have "Sample Data | QRSTE/ S179399")
[image]

The code to pull:

```
Sub GetDFInfoByDf(recordID As String, connectionString as String)

    Dim connectionString As String
    connectionString = connectionString

    Dim command As String
    command = "Select * FROM data_table WHERE id = '" & recordID & "'"
    
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    conn.Open connectionString

    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    rs.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic

    Set rs = conn.Execute(command)

    Dim rsMatrix As Variant
    rsMatrix = rs.GetRows(1)

    If IsNull(rs) Then
        'rs is null
        MsgBox "Pulled recordset is null"
    Else
        Call FillObjValuesFromRecordSet(rs)
    End If
```

I see that we have a somewhat special character in there (|)

In terms of any SQL Encoding configurations: It's most likely UTF-8. I would think that I have to convert that to ANSI either in VBA or on the SQL side, but have been running in circles to try and figure that out.

Note that this field is NVARCHAR in SQL

Any ideas on how to handle this? Documentation is very sparse on the subject, from what I've seen.

Thanks!

Things I've Tried:

1. Adding Session Mode=ANSI; to the connection string

Expected Outcome:
-SQL stores the varchar "Sample Data | QRSTE/ S179399" (no quotes in the field)
-I'm expecting my Select to return that exact varchar/string value instead of the return in the image (")

Comment: For security, you shouldn't be posting credentials with the connection string - please edit them out.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! 

I've edited post and changed the password just in case.

Technically, this is just a proof of concept DB.  I wouldn't want anyone else in it anyway.

Comment: Pipe is not really a special character, and shouldn’t be causing a whole field value to drop out.  Maybe you could share your FillObjValuesFromRecordSet method?

Comment: I Agree that Pipe is not a special char and you showed your recordset result. I would write a sql special to this single field to get the len of the data. Like select Len(yourfield) from foo where bar`'
Perhaps your expectation of the data is wrong?

Comment: I am of the opinion that posting BOGUS security credentials without disclosing they are inaccurate is a great practice. It always irks me some video/security video and the narrator puts a password of like `fakepassword` or says, "this isn't really my password". This disclosure only benefits individuals up to unethical behavior by saving them the time it takes to figure this out for themselves. Of course, the importance of it being a *BOGUS* credential vs an accurate one cannot be understated...

Comment: Seems that the length in the SQL value is correct and I don't see anything special when viewing all characters from there.

One thing that I forgot to note (will update) is that my data type on that field is nvarchar.  Assuming this might be the root of the issue, but i'll post back here.

Comment: Also note the values in the image are before I run the filling Sub

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Could it be that there is a *line break* in front of "Sample Data | QRSTE/ S179399" - as there is only one quotation mark - not two, as I would expect, if it were empty.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

My SQL table columns with varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) were not able to translate back.

My initial table had larger-than-needed sizes, so altering those columns to varchar(8000) and nvarchar(4000) fixed the issue!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can't alter the definition of the columns in SQL, you can use a cast :

For example:

```
CAST(Email AS VARCHAR(100))
```